# SFML loadFromFile doesn't work, weird error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I'm trying to load texture in SFML, but it doesn't work. Seems like the program doesn't even know that JPG exists.

```
sf::Texture table;
    if (!table.loadFromFile("pool-table.jpg"))
    {
        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
```

I've got error like this:

```
Error!
Failed to load image "
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: ***What should I do to fix this?*** Is the image in the same folder as the project? Or did you change the default setting for the working directory in the Visual Studio Debugger settings for your project? If the image is in the project folder make sure it is not named pool-table.jpg.jpg. Windows hiding of extensions can allow files accidentally being created with 2 extensions because it makes it more difficult to see.

Comment: the image is in the same folder where main.cpp is, image is named correctly

Answer (score 0):

The path is most probably the issue. You can either use relative path, or absolute path, for this to work. You're currently using a relative path, so your file must be in the *current working directory* of your program.

To be sure that the path is the issue, you can try it by using an absolute path, like this:

```
myTexture.loadFromFile("C:/Projects/MyProject/Media/myImage.png")
```

If it works this way, you know that the code isn't the problem, but the path.

If this is still a problem after this test, here's a nice trick which might save the day: just before you load the image, insert this line of code:

```
system("dir");
```

It will the current working directory to the console. Your relative paths should take this information in consideration when you type them.

Good luck!

Comment: I've tried this as well. Nothing works :/ ```system("dir");``` shows that jpg is in working directory but ```loadFromFile()``` doesn't see it

Comment: As @drescherjm said in the comments, check for hidden extensions. The problem really, really seems to be the path. Also: are you using the 32 bits or the 64 bits version of SFML? Some people with the 64 bits version had success with this kind of problem by switching to the 32 bits version (mixing x64 and x86 libraries is bad, and might cause this problem).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for comments! I've changed configuration from Debug to Release and everything started working finally :D

Comment: Maybe you had a library conflict. Did you make sure you were using debug libraries for the Debug configuration?

Comment: Yes, I had a library conflict. I were using wrong libraries in Debug configuration (without "-d"). I've linked the correct ones and now texture is loading properly.